# C#/WPF merging consecutive event calls

Tags: c#, wpf, system.reactive, throttling, win2d

Win2D features this function `Invalidate()`, that when called will redraw an entire control, and on rapid successive calls they will merge into one update that encompasses any changes from previous calls. I am trying to recreate this in my own application, but I can't find a framework that matches this description exactly.

Say every time I click a chart, a line gets added. What I want to happen is that if someone clicks 100 times in a row, it will wait until the clicking is done to add all of the lines at once, as opposed to adding them one at a time. Similarly, resizing the window should only redraw the chart once, as opposed to every time the event is fired.

I have tried using `System.Reactive`, but most of their merging/throttling seems to ignore the previous calls, and I can't use the `OnCompleted()` part of Subscribe on an event as it does not ever "complete".

Has anyone had experience with solving a problem like this? I am looking in to using timers to create a sort of delay, but I'd like to know if there is already something out there that works as described.

Comment: I don't fully understand the problem, but would data binding solve it?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480224.aspx  If you just need to create a delay, you could use "await Task.Delay()" within an async method.  If neither of those work, could you clarify?

Comment: Sure, sorry, first time posting here. Say every time I click a chart, a line gets added. What I want to happen is that if someone clicks 100 times in a row, it will wait until the clicking is done to add all of the lines at once, as opposed to adding them one at a time. Similarly, resizing the window should only redraw the chart once, as opposed to every time the event is fired.

Comment: No problem!  I'm pretty new too.  I posted a possible solution.  Hopefully that'll work for you.

Comment: @hatafark - I've just posted a simple Rx way to do what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I'd solve this.  I put this all in Mainwindow.xaml.cs for ease of understanding, but you may want to move the logic to its own class.

```
    private int clickCount;
    private DateTime lastClick;
    private System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer clickEventTimer;
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (clickEventTimer == null || !clickEventTimer.IsEnabled)
        {
            clickCount = 1;
            lastClick = DateTime.Now;
            clickEventTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer() { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) };
            clickEventTimer.Tick += (timer, args) =>
            {
                if (DateTime.Now - lastClick < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
                {
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    clickEventTimer.Stop();
                    MessageBox.Show($"Do stuff for the {clickCount.ToString()} click(s) you got.");
                }
            };
            clickEventTimer.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            clickCount++;
            lastClick = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works as expected, I added the logic for saving the calls before the if statement and it properly fires them all at once. Thank you very much!!

Comment: I know that this answer works, but this is exactly the kind of code that Rx was designed to avoid.

Comment: I don't understand why a complete, working solution that doesn't require an external library is getting down-voted.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried using System.Reactive, but most of their merging/throttling seems to ignore the previous calls, and I can't use the OnCompleted() part of Subscribe on an event as it does not ever "complete".

I think you missed some, like the [`Buffer`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/buffer.html#collapseRxNET) operator:

```
Button button = new Button();

...

var subscription = button
    .ButtonClicks()
    .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5), 100) // Perform action  after 100 clicks or after half a second, whatever comes first
    .Select(buffer => buffer.Count)
    .Subscribe(clickCount =>
    {
        // Do something with clickCount
    })
```

The helper class:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IObservable<EventPattern<RoutedEventArgs>> ButtonClicks(this Button control)
    {
        return Observable.FromEventPattern<RoutedEventHandler, RoutedEventArgs>(
                h => control.Click += h,
                h => control.Click -= h);
    }
}
```

At the end of the application:

```
subscription.Dispose();
```

Of course Buffer has some overloads:

`Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))` -> Buffer for a second, then perform action (Same result as the accepted answer)

`Buffer(100)` -> Perform action after 100 clicks

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple to do in Rx. This is what you need:

```
IObservable<long> query =
    source
        .Select(t => Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100.0)))
        .Switch();
```

So, as long as `source` is an `IObservable<T>` that produces a value whenever the user performs an action then this observable will only produce a value when there has been a `100.0` millisecond period of inactivity since the last value.

Now, you might want to tidy this up so that the query produces the original value and marshals back to the dispatcher. That's easy too.

Try this:

```
IObservable<T> query =
    source
        .Select(t =>
            Observable
                .Timer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100.0))
                .Select(_ => t))
        .Switch()
        .ObserveOnDispatcher();
```

Simple.